# SQL code unknown

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql

I found a piece of code in our cloud that was written by someone in the past, and I don't know what it does (I have no developer experience).

```vb
%%[
    if Not Empty(@zip)
        Set @rows = LookupRows("ShipTimes", "zip", @zip)

        if RowCount(@rows) == 1 then
           set @row = row(rows,1)
           set @city = Field(@row, "city")
           set @state = Field(@row, "state")
        endif
    endif
]%%
```

and another one:

```sql
SELECT
    l.ListName,
    de.SUBKey,
    l.[Status]
from
    [<de_name>] de
Join
    [_listsubscribers] l 
ON
    de.SubscriberKey = l.Subscriberkey
where
    l.listname = '<List name>'
```

Do any of you have any idea what are the codes supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMPscript-code checks if the variable "zip" isn't empty, and if so, it checks the "ShipTimes" data extension for that zip-value. If there is only one match, the values for "city" and "state" from the retrieved row are written to the corresponding AMPscript-variables.

The SQL statement retrieves the ListName and Status from the ListSubscribers-Data View for all subscribers, that exist in the data extension `<de_name>` and on the list `<List name>`. Additionally the SUBKey-column is added from `<de_name>`. The matching between the data extension and the data view is done via the Column "SubscriberKey".

**Additional Information:**

- [Data View: ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5)
- [AMPscript: LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm)